# libre office instance on top

Tags: libreoffice

hello i was wondering something.

I'm building a spreadsheet with libre office for which i have to input some data on a daily basis from a webpage, i have just one screen available so it would be very handy to keep my libre office instance on top.. so i can manipulate the webpage but still have the office instance in view.

does anyone have a solution?

i have looked in libre office and googled but i didn't find anything on the topic.

Kind regards

Matthieu

Comment: You maybe able to make LibreOffice-specific rules for your window manager, whichever that is.

Comment: If you use Ubuntu with Unity desktop (dunno about others, maybe some have it too), you can simply right-click on the titlebar of any window and check the "Always on top" option there.